# Alignment problems in Firefox

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am having an alignment issue in Firefox with my table. In Chrome/IE, it looks correct. Is there something wrong or do I need to add in an "FF Fix?"

It looks like the little dot in the bottom right corner of each cell (in chrome/ie) is in the bottom right corner of the page in FF. On the live page, however, it's in the top right of the screen somewhere.

http://jsfiddle.net/P3JnP/5/

NOTE - seems to not work in Safari, either.

Comment: Just a note, it doesn't look right in Safari either.

Comment: Good note. I'll edit the post.

Comment: Dear see my answer and let me know if i am lagging some here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the idea I have. Put a div inside your each TD and make it relative. Wrap that div around both your number and dot and make it full height and width of the cell. Something like this:

```
<td class="td_time">
   <div class="time-wrapper"><div class="time"></div><span class="time_note"></span>     
   </div>
</td>

CSS:
.time-wrapper
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
position:relative
}
```

This should fix it. Also you should be able to take out "relative" position from td_time class.

Comment: crappy solution, but the only one that exists

Comment: doesn't seem to work..now it doesn't look correct in any browser

Comment: OR, OR you can just stop using tables and use divs instead.

Answer (score 0):

See the below fiddle:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/P3JnP/11/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/P3JnP/11/embedded/result/